# onConfigurationChanged doesn't call onDestroy on activity

Tags: android

This project uses the Navigation component in order to navigate, I try to figure out what is a problem with an Activity and why it doesn't destroy. I have already simplified this activity to this

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Log.e("HERE", "activity onCreate")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Log.e("HERE", "activity onDestroy")
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        Log.e("HERE", "activity onConfigurationChanged")
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
    }
}
```

So, in the log I see that the first method called is `onCreate`, then I change the orientation and I see that `onConfigurationChanged` is called and that is it. What I actually expect is ``onConfigurationChanged`->`onDestroy()`->`onCreate()`

I assume that a possible problem could cause Navigation component as my activity is actually pure (just a few lifecycle methods).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `onConfigurationChanged()` is being called, that suggests that you have `android:configChanges` defined for this `<activity>` in the manifest.

Comment: @CommonsWare does it mean that `onDestroy()` won't be called on this activity?

Comment: If you have `android:configChanges` for this activity, then for whatever configuration changes you list there, the activity will not be destroyed and recreated. `onConfigurationChanged()` will be called, and you will be responsible for updating your UI for any actual changes.